# How to assign a label to specific item in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm working on computing minimum values from a csv row (of which I have turned into a normalised list of list) and am having trouble assigning the original csv title / header with the corresponding minimum value from that row (of which I omitted both to make the normalization easier). Below is what I am working with:

My normalised list of lists (each sublist is a row from my csv file)

```
[[0.1442722616425349, 0.011387368532690107, 1.0, 0.01016955650916749, 0.0, 0.007007584956949359], [0.13618895033835154, 0.009739033790403672, 1.0, 0.011358919624000634, 0.0, 0.007134183651352274], [0.14773629092116417, 0.015197531681779487, 1.0, 0.009581175298448931, 0.0], [0.1480962502699423, 0.01613878131072959, 1.0, 0.015035304680545728, 0.0, 0.007260689113737381], [0.1404716315950755, 0.012720171642799673, 1.0, 0.011429478548387115, 0.0, 0.005808759430147285], [0.14362441283729363, 0.008943844575022054, 1.0, 0.008400152860935555, 0.0, 0.0020931326050634305]]
```

I calculate the minimum of each sublist (row) using

```
min_list = [min(p) for p in norm_row_list]
```

and obviously the output will be

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

But what I want is instead of printing out numbers to print which column that number came from (each column has a string header, e.g. the first 0.0 is from my second last column [5] called Generosity). As well as print out the title (which is located in the first column, with the first row in that column being Afghanistan).

```
country,      header2,     header3,     header4,     header5      header6
Australia     1.0          0.3435353    0.0          0.23124234   0.35334
Algeria       0.343434     0.434343     1.0          0.0          0.344343
```

So I need to the compute the min of each row and have it out below:

```
Australia's happiness is bound by its header4
Algeria's happiness is bound by its header5
```

Comment: Your second question is not clear.

Comment: Provide more data (including the names you are mentioning). That should help provide better solutions.

Comment: Added some extra data

Comment: Your example must have 7 columns. Right? (because your lists have 6 elements)

Comment: Yep, just updated it to reflect it sorry

Answer (score 1):

Let `headers` be column headers and `list_of_lists` all the other rows (including the country column). Then the following do what you want:

```
headers = ['country', ...]

for mList in list_of_lists:
  cur_min = 1000
  min_index = 0
  for col_index, item in enumerate(mList[1:]):
    if item < cur_min:
      cur_min = item
      min_index = col_index
  print(mList[0] + "'s happiness is bound by its " + headers[min_index + 1])
```

If the minimum is always 0, then the above code can be simplified.

Example of the above mentioned variables:

```py
list_of_lists = [['Australia',1.0,0.3435353,0.0,0.23124234,0.35334],['Algeria',0.343434,0.434343,1.0,0.0,0.344343]]
headers = ['country','a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with using pandas, this can be done pretty easily.
First import you CSV into pandas as dataframe with

```
df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv') #need to look-up other postas which will help you read your CSV into pandas as a dataframe.
```

Then use the below code.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print (row['country,'] + ' happiness is bound by its ' + df.columns[row.values == 0][0])
```

My input is the data frame as below

```
    country,    header2,    header3,    header4,    header5
0   Australia   1.000000    0.343535    0.0     0.231242
1   Algeria     0.343434    0.434343    1.0     0.000000
```

**Ouput**

```
Australia happiness is bound by its header4,
Algeria happiness is bound by its header5
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question fully but this would allow you to read in a CSV and output what you're looking for without having to put it into a list of lists.  I avoided things like pandas because it's gibangous and maybe that's overkill.  Those libraries are for sure the way to go for more complex work, though.

for a csv similar to this structure

```
country,header1,header2,header3,header4,header5,header6
Algeria,1,2,55,3,2,3
Australia,33,2,8,3,99,0
UnitedStates,9,8,7,6,5,4
```

You could use this code

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', newline="\n") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        # do whatever normalization to row values you need to do
        minval = min(([v for i,v in enumerate(row.values()) if i != 0]))
        i = [v for i,v in enumerate(row.values()) if i != 0].index(minval)
        h = [r for r in row.keys()][i+1]
        print(f"{row['country']}'s happiness is bound by its {h}")
```

If you have to work from   a list of lists, you can put the headers into a variable, capture the index of the minimum value with the `list.index` function and reference the correct header from that index the same way I initialized `i` in the snippet I pasted.

```
headers = ['header1', 'header2', ...]
countries = ['a', 'bunch', 'o', 'countries', ...]
for ci,row in enumerate(list_of_lists):
    minval = min(row)
    i = row.index(minval)
    h = headers[i]
    print(f"{countries[ci]}'s happiness is bound by its {h}")
```

I hope I caught what you were shooting for.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
header = ['country', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4', 'header5', 'header6']

[header[p.index(min(p))] for p in norm_row_list]

# ['header5', 'header5', 'header5', 'header5', 'header5', 'header5']
```

Given that `norm_row_list` you provided above.